# Android - TextView exibindo letras gradativamente

Tags: java, android

Como faço para que um TextView exiba o texto gradativamente, mostrando letra por letra? Procurei na internet e achei alguns tutoriais sobre efeito TypeWriter, porém não consegui usar.

main.xml:

```
<TextView 
android:text="TEXTO"
android:id="@+id/txt"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/pixel.ttf");

txt.setTypeface(font);
```